# background-image in react component

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm building a page and I want a Material UI element to have a background image using `background-image` CSS property. I have googled it of course, and there are solutions but for some reason, I can't see that image.

P.S.1: even changing that Material UI element to regular  hasn't helped me at all.

P.S.2: when I'm using  inside container it shows, but that's not what I want.

UPDATE1: Tried adding height and width to container, still no luck...

```
import React from 'react';

import Paper from 'material-ui/Paper';

import IconButton from 'material-ui/IconButton';
import ActionHome from 'material-ui/svg-icons/action/home';


const styles = {
    paperContainer: {
        backgroundImage: `url(${"static/src/img/main.jpg"})`
    }
};

export default class Home extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <Paper style={styles.paperContainer}>

            </Paper>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I've found a fix for my case. Actually setting container height in pixels have helped.

Here's the code:

```
import React from 'react';


const styles = {
    paperContainer: {
        height: 1356,
        backgroundImage: `url(${"static/src/img/main.jpg"})`
    }
};

export default class Home extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div style={styles.paperContainer}>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 70):

You have to import the image as the following, using the relative path.

```
import React from 'react';

import Paper from 'material-ui/Paper';

import IconButton from 'material-ui/IconButton';
import ActionHome from 'material-ui/svg-icons/action/home';

import Image from '../img/main.jpg'; // Import using relative path


const styles = {
    paperContainer: {
        backgroundImage: `url(${Image})`
    }
};

export default class Home extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <Paper style={styles.paperContainer}>
                Some text to fill the Paper Component
            </Paper>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Have not helped unfortunately :(

Comment: To be able to import and use images like this you need to use https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader
@Roman are you using it?

Comment: @EugeneTsakh yes I do have that dependency met. Bundle goes without an error. ("file-loader": "^0.11.2")

Comment: Mmmmh that is weird, it works on my simple create-react-app...
Did you try to use the image in a simple `<img src={Image} />` to see if the import works ?

Oh I might have found it ! Did you put some text in your `<Paper>` just to check if my solution works ? I just updated my answer

Comment: I've posted an answer to this question already, however, I've just tried your solution too. Does not work for me :(

Comment: yes I think if you created your app using create-react-app then install material ui, that should be all required, perhaps somethigns gone wrong with the setup of your app, maybe simpler todo create react app again and then npm start and fix it where it breaks, (I expect a few `npm install package-name --save`  would be required. I think this is one of those circumstances when the scorched earth approach would be best

Answer (score 10):

I got this to work for material-ui, where the padding on my parent element was 24px so I added 48px to the width of the background image to make it work...

```
const styles = {
   heroContainer: {
     height: 800,
     backgroundImage: `url(${"../static/DSC_1037.jpg"})`,
     backgroundSize: 'cover',
     backgroundPosition: 'center',
     width: `calc(100vw + 48px)`,
     margin: -24,
     padding: 24,
   }
  };
<Grid
    container
    direction="column"
    justify="flex-end"
    alignItems="right"
    style={styles.heroContainer} >
    <Grid item>Goes here</Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: This is supposed to be the Accepted answer

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issues while working with Material UI React and the Create React App. Here is the solution that worked for me. Note that I set up a webpack alias for the relative path

```
import BackgroundHeader from "assets/img/BlueDiamondBg.png"

const BackgroundHead = {
  backgroundImage: 'url('+ BackgroundHeader+')'
  }

<div style={BackgroundHead}>
```

Answer (score 2):

Like Romainwn said, you need to import the image to the file. Make sure you use the relative path to parent, so instead of

```
static/src/img/main.jpg    #looks for static folder from current file location
```

Do

```
/static/src/img/main.jpg #looks for file from host directory:
```

Another hack to do it would be adding an inline style tag to the component:

```
import React from 'react';

import Paper from 'material-ui/Paper';

import IconButton from 'material-ui/IconButton';
import ActionHome from 'material-ui/svg-icons/action/home';

import Image from '../img/main.jpg'; // Import using relative path


export default class Home extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <Paper style="background:path/to/your/image;">

            </Paper>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can you sx props in MUI v5

```
import React from 'react';

import Paper from 'material-ui/Paper';

import Image from '../img/main.jpg';


export default class Home extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <Paper sx={{ backgroundImage: `url(${Image})` }}>

            </Paper>
        )
    }
}
```